# MySQL Asynchronous Database in One Server

Tags: mysql

I have two database in one mysql server `database_master` and `database_backup`.
I would like `database_backup` to copy all new data that inserted into or updated at `database_master`.
But is there is some data deleted on `database_master`, the data on `database_backup` will be still remain.

How can we do that in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, I take it that you want replication, but not to replicate deletes of records.  This cannot be done with the native replication (neither row nor statement based).  The main reason is if on the main db you deleted a row then inserted a row the new row might get the old row's primary key.  On the replica db this would cause a key conflict.

However, to do some kind of hack audit logging, you could create on the slave mysql server one logging table for each actual DB table. For example, if you had a table `foo` you would create a corresponding `foo_logging` table.  The logging tables would have every column in the original, plus a seperate auto-incrementing primary key.  You'd then put a trigger on the original table to insert a copy of any new or updated record into it's corresponding logging table.

Comment: Can you suggest mysql application that can do it?

Comment: @GusDeCooL See my update for a hack solution.  I don't know of any free system that does what you need, but I'd be suprised if there weren't all kinds of commercial compliance auditing solutions that do just what you need.  If not their should be... I'd poke around Percona's website if no one here has a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use TRIGGERs on the database_master table for the insert and update statements. In the trigger, you can insert the data in the database_backup table.

However, note that this won't be asynchronous. The insert (or update) in both tables will together be one transaction. If something goes wrong, both will be rolled back (which is a good thing in some cases).

Deletes on the database_master won't affect database_backup.